# How to consume System.Action after use

Tags: c#, delegates

I am using delegates to communicate between my classes like this

```
 public event System.Action OnAdFinishedOk;
```

however, every time I subscribe to this event, after use it, I need to remove like this `adsManager.OnAdFinishedOk -= Revivir;`

I can introduce bugs if I forget to unsubscribe from the delegate,

Is any way to make a subscription to a delegate and consume the subscription after the use, so I don't need to unsubscribe? (I am open to another approach)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/weak-event-patterns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar situation and I solve it like:

```
public void Register(Action action) {
    Action _action = null;
    _action = ()=> {
        action();
        OnAdFinishedOk -= _action;
    }
    OnAdFinishedOk += _action;
}
```

Hope it helps!